# Query to find distinct rows on the basis of Id

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

```
data = [
   {id:1, type:1},
   {id:2, type:2},
   {id:1, type:3},
   {id:2, type:2}
]
```

table1 column(id, type)

I have to push the data in table1 such that it should have only rows with unique id, rows which are exact same can be removed by using distinct but for the rows that has same id but different type for that I want the rows whose comes last( or larger index like in example for id:1 I want it to be of type 3), I am not able to figure out this problem.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2017

Comment: You want the maximum type per ID then? `SELECT ID, MAX(Type) from whatever GROUP BY ID`

Comment: no it doesn't depend if it's maximum or min it should be the last one

Comment: how do you know which is the last ?

Comment: i have a json, which i am inserting into a table it can have multiple object of same id  so it should have latest object with same id at last

Comment: @sonugupta, do you want these two rows as result: `(id, type) = (1, 3), (2, 2)`?

Comment: @sonugupta, also note that this JSON is not valid, you need to fix it somehow and parse it appropriately.

Comment: you know in your json what is the last, but not anymore in your table. So, this is not an sql question then ?

Comment: @Zhorov (id, type) = (1, 3), (2, 2) yes it should be the result and yes i have to handle this problem at sql level

Comment: how do you know at sql level which is the last ?

Answer (score 0):

The input data is almost a JSON, so a possible approach is to fix the input and parse it with `OPENJSON()`. The result from the first `OPENJSON()` is a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type` and in case of a JSON array the `key` column returns the 0-based index of each item in this array.

```
DECLARE @data nvarchar(max) = N'[
   {id:1, type:1},
   {id:2, type:2},
   {id:1, type:3},
   {id:2, type:2}
]'

SELECT id, [type]
FROM (
   SELECT 
      j2.*,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY j2.id ORDER BY CONVERT(int, j1.[key]) DESC) AS rn
   FROM OPENJSON(REPLACE(REPLACE(@data, 'id', '"id"'), 'type', '"type"')) j1
   CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value]) WITH (
      id int '$.id',
      [type] int '$.type'
   ) j2
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Result:

```
id  type
--------
1   3
2   2
```